# Git: How to pull config files once, then leave them untouched after

Tags: git

I currently have a couple of configuration files, let's call them config.php and config2.php. I have developers working on this repository, and these configuration files are necessary to host local dev environments, so I placed them in the git repository. Once pulled, I want them to remain untouched, even by pushes and pulls, etc.

After adding the config files to the .gitignore, I still have to make sure that the config files are set to production values when I push, then reset them to my local when I pull. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

## Hooks

Use a pre-receive hook to decline changes to the config file (maybe except when the commit message has a special keyword or line).
In this case, adding the config files to `.gitignore` is unnecessary (it is useless anyway - once they files are tracked, it does not matter if they are in `.gitignore` or not).

If you need to distinguish between production/test versions, that you simply have to make sure the test versions are not merged into the production branches (this can also be enforced by hooks).

## Scripts

Let the configuration files be automatically generated by a script. The generated files are placed in `.gitignore` and never tracked.
This way, local developers once call `createConfig.sh` and can adapt to their local needs.
If the configuration changes, update `createConfig.sh`—developers then need to adapt the changes locally as well (either by deleting and re-creating, or simply reproducing the changes manually).

In your production environment, you can also simply have a local copy.
Ideally, `createConfig.sh` generates production-ready values, so not many manual changes are required. (Of course, adding a `--testing` switch is always possible.)

Answer (score 0):

If you add files to your git repository, then git is going to track them.  That's just how it works.

A solution for your particular situation might be to *not* include those files in the repository, and instead include something like `config.php.sample` and `config2.php.sample`, and then instruct your developers, when first cloning the repository, to make local copies with the appropriate filenames.